# Dynamic column name using cursor in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to generate the column name dynamically in loop and access the column in oracle table using PLSQL. How do I do that?

```
DECLARE
 varValue VARCHAR(20);
 CURSOR c IS
  SELECT * FROM TEST1;
 BEGIN
     FOR i IN c LOOP
       FOR j IN 1..5
       LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ''NAME1'||to_Char(j)||''' from dual' INTO varValue;
         dbms_output.put_line(j);
         dbms_output.put_line(i.varValue);
       END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
 END;
```

Actual issue is, I need to acccess the cell values of each row (i) given by cursor (c) like i.name11, i.name12....i.name1100. The logic to be deployed in each cell is same. So i need the column name used here i.e. name11 to be generated dynamically. That is alread done and stored to a variable varValue. Now how can i access the cells i.varValue such that var value is generated in the loop.

The error is as follows:

```
ORA-06550: line 14, column 34:
PLS-00302: component 'VARVALUE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 14, column 11:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Is it possible to alias the column with a known name? That way you could always use that to retrieve the value.

Comment: I don't understand your concern. Post your full requirements because in the way you ask it's hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
 varValue VARCHAR(20);
 CURSOR c IS
  SELECT * FROM TEST1;
 BEGIN
     FOR i IN c LOOP
       FOR j IN 1..5
       LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ''NAME1'||to_Char(j)||''' from dual' INTO varValue;
         dbms_output.put_line(j);
         dbms_output.put_line('NAME1'||to_Char(j)||' : '||varValue);
       END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
 END;
```

Comment: Thanks OracleUser, Still we can say this is syntactically correct... :(. Specify full requirement